# Does kafka holds capability of rule-engine?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are using kafka for messaging and lot more stuff but now there is a requirement where we need some kind of rule-engine for data processing based on some rules. Does kafka holds any capability like this (rule-engine) or we have to use third party rule engine's (eg. https://camunda.com/dmn/ ) only and integrate with kafka.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to use a third party rule engine with Apache Kafka. As part of the project there is [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/) and also to ease off a bit the need to write Java code to express rules there is [ksqlDB](https://ksqldb.io/) that is based on a subset of ANSI SQL.

While these options are not necessarily a rule engine per-se; they share the same semantics which is: given an intermediate processing output the relevant result based on the computation. The difference will be in the how and not in the what. So I think they are decent replacements.

You can always integrate both as well. Several rule engines such as Drools from Red Hat are Java-based and thus; can be easily accessed from a Kafka Streams processor. As long the if-then-else rules run in the same JVM space of the Kafka Streams application you won't have any performance penalties other than a possibly bigger JVM heap.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Ricardo. Firstly I am not in favor of any rule engine but want to clear one doubt that like for e.g. camunda DMN provides very smooth and easy to use rule sets which can be defined easily and can be changed dynamically. For these kind of things I think we need to write the code in kafka streams. I want dynamic loading of rules. Can you suggest few examples where kafka streams are being used as a rule-engine

Comment: @aggarwalb Rules could be stored in a topic (much like KSQL queries are stored), then your rule processor would have a consumer thread to dynamically update itself while consuming any data that needs to flow through the engine.

Comment: Right. The idea that I proposed doesn't ask you to replace the rule engine for Kafka Streams but instead -- to use Kafka Streams as your processing layer that feeds off the rule engine to do the computation required. Hence why the Drools example. You could write a stream processor that would access Drools programatically and thus perform the if-then-else behavior desired given the input stream. Here is an example of Drools usage via Java: https://www.baeldung.com/drools.

Note that Drools also support decision tables, just like Camunda =)

Comment: All in all, what I can cater from the answers is that there is not ready made rule-engine in kafka but we can use kafka streams for rule processing